# Weakref not getting deleted in REPL even after manual gc collection

Tags: python

I am also seeing this issue when executing the below code in REPL, even after manually doing `gc.collect()` i can still see the weakref object. See below

```
 [67]: from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1


a = A()

w = WeakValueDictionary()

w['k1'] = a

dict(w)
Out[72]: {'k1': <__main__.A at 0x1e59e9b84a8>}

del a 

gc.collect()
Out[74]: 239

dict(w)
Out[75]: {'k1': <__main__.A at 0x1e59e9b84a8>}
```

Ideally the weakref should be cleared once the strong ref has been deleted and a manual gc has been done, but why I am still seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like like you are using IPython.  As described in [the docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html?highlight=_oh#output-caching-system), IPython stores each output in a numbered global variable.  Thus there is a global variable `_72` that holds a reference to `dict(w)` (the value that was output in `Out[72]`), which of course contains a strong refence to the object formerly known as `a`.